# Use Excel to Check Sharepoint Document Library Subsubfolder if Empty

Tags: excel, sharepoint

In Excel,  column A consists of various sharepoint document library subfolder names under same document library: "Subfolder 001", "Subfolder 002" etc.; row 1 consists of typical sharepoint document library subsubfolders names: "01. Subsubfolder 1", "02. Subsubfolder 2", "03. Subsubfolder 3". Wish to use excel to check if any file in each subsubfolder in each subfolder within sharepoint document library. Any idea? This will help to summarise at one glance.